# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos que tengo en una BD en el cuerpo de un correo electrónico?

Tags: android, sqlite

Necesito mostrar los datos que tengo ya guardados en SQLite en un correo electrónico para mandar esa información.
Esos reportes se tienen que reflejar automáticamente en el cuerpo del correo seleccionando de que fecha a qué fecha quisieras los reportes.
Espero me puedan ayudar ya que soy nuevo en Android Studio.
GRACIAS!

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"aaron.armienta@hotmail.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Prueba");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Prueba de AgroFuel");


    try{
        DataBaseHelper dbh= new DataBaseHelper(this);
        //HashMap<Long, Car> test= dbh.getCars();
        Log.d(TAG, "Iniciando");
        Log.d(TAG, "test1: "+dbh.getCars().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "test2: "+dbh.getExpenses().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "test3: "+dbh.getBodyTypes().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "test4: "+dbh.getGasolineTypes().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "Terminando");
        dbh.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(SendMailActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Una consulta, los correos que necesitas provienen de las funciones que estas loggeando? Ejemplo dbh.getCars().toString()??

Comment: Así, los datos que tengo que mostrar en el cuerpo del correo provienen de las funciones que tengo ahí.
Solo necesito saber cómo le hago para mostrar esos datos que tengo guardados en un correo